# multi user chat in smack

Tags: openfire, smack

I am a new user of SMACK chat API. I am trying to write a multi user chat application but not able to do it. Can anyone give me simple full version of code for this.

Here is my code

```
    ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("127.0.0.1",5222);
    connection = new XMPPConnection(config);
    connection.connect();
    connection.login("aa", "bb");

    MultiUserChat muc = new MultiUserChat(connection, "test@testdomain");
    muc.join("nick");
```

Comment: Please give some sort of idea what problems you're encountering. You say you're 'not able to do it' - will your code not compile? Are you getting errors on the console? What do the error messages say?

Answer (score 0):

One thing I notice about your code is that you do not add a message listener anywhere. Your code will not be notified of new messages unless you call something like 
muc.addMessageListener(...